# angularjs page navigation not working properly

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
angular.module('mobApp', ['ionic', 'mobApp.controllers','ngCordova', 'mobApp.services', 'mobApp.directive', 'yaru22.angular-timeago', 'monospaced.elastic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider

```
    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })
  .state('app.search', {
    url: '/search',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/search.html'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.page1', {
      url: '/page1',
      templateUrl: 'templates/page1.html',
      controller: 'PageCtrl'
  })
  .state('app.page2', {
      url: '/page2',
      templateUrl: 'templates/page2.html',
      controller: 'PageCtrl'
  })
  .state('app.page3', {
      url: '/page3',
      templateUrl: 'templates/page3.html',
      controller: 'PageCtrl'
  })    
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/search');
```

`index.html`

```
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
```

inside `search.html` i have `<a href="#/app.page1">page1</a>` when i click this link its not working properly. its showing back my expected page navigation is

`search.html - > page1.html - > page2.html -> page3.html`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the angular ui-router. Please be aware of the difference between urls and states. If you want to navigate to the state named `app.page1` you have two options.

1. `<a href="#/app/page1">...</a>` as you defined the urls for the (nested) state.
2. `<a ui-sref="app.page1">...</a>` using the directive provided by the ui-router to navigate using state names (the first argument in the .state() call).

The second way is preferred as it allows you to change the states' urls without modifying all the links you already set up. Also letting the library build the final urls makes it easier to switch from the anchor links (#/...) to the html5 mode with one simple flag.

Depending on the devices you are targeting, you may want to insert an empty href (href="") for the browsers to render the link correctly.

For more details, please check out the docs at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref

Comment: `<a href="#/app/page1"  class="button button-light">page1</a>` is not going  to page1

Comment: The recommended version is using ui-sref. The href will only work with html5mode disabled (See the docs). Have you tried the ui-sref variant?

Comment: Great answer! ajaegie, I want to master my ionic knowledge. Where have you started off learning the framework? ;)

Comment: `<a ui-sref="app.page2">page2</a>` doesnt work either

Comment: Could you please provide a little more context on your setup? How does your main site (some kind of index.html) look like? How do you have configured the insertion point (**ui-view**) for the routing? Probably there is a problem with this setup. Looks like you are using **named views** (like for app.search) but not everywhere. See: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Comment: Check out http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-view#example. The ion-nav-view is the ionic version of ui-view. As you can see, there are either named or unnamed views, you mixed both in the sample above. Also make sure, your ng-app name (starter) matches the name where you define the module (mobApp). See a code sample here on the right: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/